# compiling git on HP-UX

Tags: git, compile, hp-ux

I'm trying to compile git on an HP-UX system. and when i run make all, I get a syntax error on line 252. if i go to line 252 of the makefile, i see

```
uname_O := $(shell sh -c 'uname -o 2>/dev/null || echo not')
```

I've tried a couple ways to correct this error, removing the line and changing it to a hardcoded value, but even if i comment the line, remove the line, change it, or anything else, i still get a syntax error on line 252.  has anyone successfully compiled git on hp-ux without using the gcc compiler?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used HP-UX, but on FreeBSD when I get these kind of errors it's invariably the version of make that is installed.  BSD systems (and I think HP-UX is based on BSD) use the BSDMake (or pmake) program, whereas Linux uses [Gnu Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

You may like to try installing [Gnu Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) first and then using that to compile git.

Comment: can it be installed without root access? as i do not have root on this system.

Comment: In HP-UK specifically I have no idea.  You may be able to compile it from source - as long as it doesn't need GNU make to compile... (chicken... egg...)

Comment: I know right. Okay, not a magic bullet type answer that I was hoping for, but it is what it is. thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Try [this guide](http://blog.boreas.ro/2008/03/porting-git-to-hp-ux-pa-risc-and-aix.html) for compiling and installing git on HPUX.
- Download the pre-compiled package and the required dependencies [here](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Development/Tools/git-1.8.5.3/).